# Sinatra - CSS and Javascripts not loading on certain pages

Tags: browser, sinatra

I'm currently developing an admin dashboard using Sinatra, and I'm finding for one route in particular, my stylesheets and javascripts aren't working.

The route is `'/users/:id/?'`

For some reason, when I hit that page, the browser is looking for `http::localhost:9393/users/css/my_stylesheet.css` instead of `public/css/my_stylesheet.css` and so-on. Why is this happening with this route? The layout file (containing the stylesheet and script links) is that same for this route as it is for any other.

Comment: do you have :static and :public set?

Comment: :static and :public are set by default if you have a 'public' folder in your root directory, which I have. As I said, I don't have this problem with any of my other routes.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the other routes, and the code you use to reference the assets in the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Went on the #sinatra IRC channel and asked. My problem was how I was referencing the links in my haml views. I need to use the url helper `#{url ('/path/to/asset.css')}` in my code instead of hard-coding the links in.